# ignore the display of nav under div element with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code below

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right hidden-xs">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Accueil</a></li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#solutions">Nos solutions</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="page-scroll drop dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#sms">Nos services</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="sms.html">SMS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#wboardsuite">W Board Suite</a></li>
            <li><a href="esb.html">ESB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#afbl">AFBL</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#histoire">Notre Histoire</a></li>
        <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Nos References</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="page-scroll drop dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#blog">blog</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="blog-full-width.html">full-width Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog-sidebar.html">sidebar blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

knowing that i use Bootstrap , and jquery and mmenu jquery to display the nav(for mobile size) and i am obliged to add both of **div id=navbar** and the **nav id=menu** but on the browser the div is hidden by the nav 

what Attribute CSS to add to ignore the style of the nav ?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what exactly you do want.

Comment: the nav is under the div,it effects the display of the div element , i want to ignore the nav

Comment: the nav is inside the `div id=navbar`. Are you talking about this div or any other div that is above or below the nav?

Comment: Yes i talk about the div id navbar above the nav, i want it to be displayed on first level i tried #navbar > nav {z-index:0} but it didn't work

Comment: I may not be understanding you properly, but `<div id="navbar">` is the parent of that nav, so it cannot have a z-index higher than the `nav`. You either need to put the nav outside that div, or some other workaround.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 1):

[HIDDEN VISIBLE LINK](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

I have not quite understood your question .. I think you mean to hide the bar depending on which dispostivo're without ID.
You can use hidden or visible, and play with them to show or hide depending on which device you are!

Comment: @Mahran you have in the navbar <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right hidden-xs"> hidden-xs, what are you hiding for mobile mode